# Embedded linux PPC32 dynamic memory checking tool?

Tags: c++, linux, embedded

The system has only 128 MB ram and I couldn't successfully run valgrind, it will just run out of memory and too slow to be usable. The processor is also very slow.

Is there a simpler tool on PPC32 to check for heap corruption/leaks for PPC 32 with very limited resource?

I am thinking maybe something small like libsegfault.so that can be used with LD_PRELOAD , but to check for malloc/free problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electric Fence is ideal for this use case (and does leverage `LD_PRELOAD`, can be combined with `libsegfault.so`).

In addition to efence, you can use other features, some of which will end up costing cycles and/or additional memory overhead (though still likely significantly less than `valgrind`):

- `gcc`'s [mudflaps](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Mudflap_Pointer_Debugging)
- `gcc`'s fortify-source
- `glibc`'s [`mcheck()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html), `MALLOC_CHECK_`
- `clang`'s [address sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html)